# How to show a picture on the screen with assembly on Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, drawing

I want to make a game in Linux assembly. Is there a way to show (or draw) a picture on the screen via Linux kernel system calls?

I searched for it, but all the results that I get is about DOS assembly language.

Comment: for windows http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=3200020&fromSeriesID=320

Comment: +1 for trying to code a game in assembly. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do, but it seems like an incredibly tedious and slow way to develop software in assembly these days.

Assuming you're running on an i386 platform (the syscall ABI is different for each platform), look at uClibcs libc/sysdeps/linux/i386/syscall.S:

```
.text
.global syscall
.type   syscall,%function
syscall:
    pushl %ebp
    pushl %edi
    pushl %esi
    pushl %ebx

    movl  44(%esp),%ebp /* Load the 6 syscall argument registers */
    movl  40(%esp),%edi
    movl  36(%esp),%esi
    movl  32(%esp),%edx
    movl  28(%esp),%ecx
    movl  24(%esp),%ebx
    movl  20(%esp),%eax /* Load syscall number into %eax.  */
    int $0x80

    popl %ebx
    popl %esi
    popl %edi
    popl %ebp

    cmpl $-4095,%eax
    jae  __syscall_error
    ret         /* Return to caller.  */

.size syscall,.-syscall
```

This assumes all of the syscall arguments, as well as the syscall number have been loaded on the stack.

You can find the syscall numbers in the Linux kernels include/asm-generic/unistd.h file.

Now that you know how to call system calls from assembly you still need to know which system calls to call of course. I'd suggest reading up on the [Linux Framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer). Interacting with X is going to be even more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I used to write stuff in assembler as a hobbyist when I was kid. Now I regard it as much too slow and unportable - surely you want your game to run on an [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)-based phone too?  But assembly doesn't really give you that unless you completely rewrite the program after writing it for x86 and perhaps x86-64.

If you really want to do assembler, you'll probably find that your biggest hurdle is figuring out how to call the various C-API functions required, because almost everything on Linux uses a C API at one level or another. The best way to deal with that is probably to write a tiny C program that does what you need, and then compile it with:

```
gcc -S t.c
```

This should give you assembler for something similar to what you need to do, in a file named `t.s`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use kernel functions only, you must take the vesa framebuffer: [Using the framebuffer device under Linux](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/fb.html). Have fun =)